# Is this a different Travelex chip and pin card?

Tags: chip-card

Previously, it was said that Travelex didn't provide a product in the US market, but I just found this on their website today:  http://www.travelex.com/US/Products/Cash-Passport/

It seems to offer the card in the US -- I started the process and it requires a purchase (at least of Euros) of $675 (roughly US$1100).

Has anyone else tried/bought this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because spam

Answer (score 1):

*"Previously, it was said..."* - by whom, where and when? I've been using travelex chip'n'pin cards for at least several years now.